# How can I set the menu order in adobe air app?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex3, adobe

How can I set a menu order in adobe air, so that dynamically added menu's can be positioned as desired?

```
var menu1 = iconMenu.addItem(new air.NativeMenuItem('Menu 1')); 
var menu2 = iconMenu.addItem(new air.NativeMenuItem('Menu 2')); 
var menu4 = iconMenu.addItem(new air.NativeMenuItem('Menu 4'));

// Menu 3 added dynamically later
var menu3 = iconMenu.addItem(new air.NativeMenuItem('Menu 3'));
```

I want to position the menu3 in between menu2 and menu4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using the `NativeMenu` class, in that case you are looking for the [`addItemAt`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeMenu.html#addItemAt%28%29) method, which takes an index parameter that defines the position where the item should be added:

```
var menu3 = iconMenu.addItemAt(new air.NativeMenuItem('Menu 3'), 2);
```